# Unable to modify contents of file using grunt copy

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
            expand: true,
            cwd: './api/services',
            src: 'constants.js',
            dest: './assets/js',
            options: {
                process: function (content, srcpath) {
                    return content.replace(/module\.exports\.(\w*)\s=\sfunction/,"function $1")
                }
            }
```

I want to replace module.exports.funcName = func() to func funcName() .

Comment: This looks to me that it works. Maybe there is an issue with another part of your configuration? Is there an error message written to your console?

Comment: No error message. The file is being copied but the contents are not getting replaced as desired

Comment: Do you know what version of grunt-contrib-copy you are using?

Comment: yeah.  using 0.5.0

Comment: I don't know what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 4 years old, but I just ran into the same problem, so hopefully it helps others. The solution for me was to define "options" outside of "files". I'm not sure if this would've helped the OP, since they didn't mention if their options were defined within "files" to begin with.

Given the particular example above:

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: './api/services',
                src: 'constants.js',
                dest: './assets/js',
                options: {
                    process: function (content, srcpath) {
                        return content.replace(/module\.exports\.(\w*)\s=\sfunction/,"function $1")
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

to this:

```
copy: {
    main: {
        options: {
            process: function (content, srcpath) {
                return content.replace(/module\.exports\.(\w*)\s=\sfunction/,"function $1")
            }
        },
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: './api/services',
                src: 'constants.js',
                dest: './assets/js'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```